# Checks for defined data in component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have config-items for my component. If they are available they should be in the output - otherwise not.

```
cfg = { name: "sam", address: "NY", age: 51 };
...
<p *ngIf="cfg.name != undefined">{{cfg.name}}</p>
<p *ngIf="cfg.address != undefined">{{cfg.address}}</p>
<p *ngIf="cfg.age != undefined">{{cfg.age}}</p>
```

The check for defined is pretty annoying if there are a lot of items.

Is there a way to do it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the safe navigation operator (also known as optional chaining)

```
<p>{{cfg?.name}}</p>
<p>{{cfg?.address}}</p>
<p>{{cfg?.age}}</p>
```

Another option is to create a wrapping ng-container and apply the `*ngIf` on it.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cfg">
  <p>{{cfg.name}}</p>
  <p>{{cfg.address}}</p>
  <p>{{cfg.age}}</p>
</ng-container>
```